# How to make CXF Logging feature work with SOAP messages?

Tags: java, soap, log4j, cxf

I have logging set up for CXF. It is successfully logging using log4j. As a test I have modified the settings in `log4j.properties`, where the root logger is set to `INFO`.

Adding `log4j.logger.org.apache.cxf=DEBUG, C` causes CXF logging to appear in the log file. However, SOAP messages are not getting logged as they hit the server. I have set up `cxf.xml` as [the guide](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/configuration.html) dictates. The file looks like this:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/core" xsi:schemaLocation="http://cxf.apache.org/core 
  http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/core.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd">

    <cxf:bus>
      <cxf:features>
        <cxf:logging />
      </cxf:features>
    </cxf:bus>
</beans>
```

This file, when packaged in the .war, is in `/WEB-INF/classes/cxf.xml`. Based on my reading, this is all that is necessary to have CXF start logging inbound and outbound messages.

I have:

1. Successfully replaced log4j as CXF's default logger.
2. Added the logging feature to the cxf bus.
3. Ensured that CXF components are able to log.
4. Additionally specified the specific loggers as allowable:

   ```
   log4j.logger.org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor=DEBUG, C
   log4j.logger.org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor=DEBUG, C
   ```

The raw soap messages however, refuse to get logged. What am I doing wrong?

edit: adding web.xml and applicationContext.xml as requested

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
  <context-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <listener>
      <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <servlet>
      <servlet-name>cxf</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>cxf</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <session-config>
      <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
  </session-config>
</web-app>
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:soap="http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/soap"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.5.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
     http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd"
   default-dependency-check="none" default-lazy-init="false">

<!-- Load the needed resources that are present in the cxf* jars -->
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml"/>
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-soap.xml"/>
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml"/>

<!--Endpoint Info is below here -->
</beans>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried adding it to your WEB-INF/cxf-servlet.xml?  The following configuration works for logging server side messages.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
    xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/core" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
     http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd
     http://cxf.apache.org/core 
     http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/core.xsd">

    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml" />

    <cxf:bus>
        <cxf:features>
            <cxf:logging />
        </cxf:features>
    </cxf:bus>  

    <jaxws:endpoint ... />        
</beans>
```

This assumes that you are declaring your services according to CXF's [Writing a service with Spring](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/writing-a-service-with-spring.html).

As for cxf.xml, I believe that may be for client configuration, although I could not locate any supporting documentation.

Comment: I don't have a cxf-servlet.xml. CXF's documentation suggests using application-context.xml instead because it doesn't load everything. http://cxf.apache.org/docs/configuration.html is the guide I've been relying on. The applicationContext.xml has the same import statements, which should load the feature regardless of which config file it's in, right?

Comment: Yes, you can use cxf-servlet.xml or configure it to use your own file with contextConfigLocation in web.xml.  Either way, you should be able to add the logging feature.  Can you post your web.xml and applicationContext.xml if this is still not working?

Comment: Yes, posted. Now the three necessary files are posted. cxf.xml, which has the logging framework info and is imported by applicationContext.xml, which is in turn declared by web.xml.

Comment: I don't see where you are importing the cxf.xml you created, just the one from the CXF jars.  Also, did you try adding the cxf:bus config with the logging feature to your applicationContext.xml?  I would skip the cxf.xml, and just add it there.

Comment: I did try that. I added xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/core" as a namespace definition, and added the cxf:bus to the ApplicaitonContext.xml directly. Deployment fails when I do this citing "The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'cxf:bus'"

Comment: Figured it out. I needed to add the relevant schemas to the bean definitions. It appears to be logging the messages now!

Comment: @ZachMelnick Could you share which were the relevant schemas here? I'm experiencing exactly the same issue and haven't yet figured it out.

Comment: Figured it out, in my case at least, there's a good example on the CXF site which defines all the necessary namespaces and schemas: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/interceptors.html